# Why do we need to use MCT to prove linearity of integral for arbitrary function?

Tags: real-analysis, probability, probability-theory

I am currently self-studying probability theory and having a problem in proving the linearity of integral for arbitrary functions.

In the textbook, we can use a sequence of simple functions to approximate arbitrary functions(random variables), and it's constructed by:
$$ f_n(x)=\sum_{i=1}^{n\cdot 2^n} \frac{i-1}{2^n}\cdot1_{[\frac{i-1}{2^n},\frac{i}{2^n}]}(x)\ +\ n\cdot1_{[1,+\infty]} $$

and we denote $$Z_n^X=f_n(X),\ \ Z_n^Y=f_n(Y)$$

Why can't we write:
$$\int (aX+bY)\ d\mu\ = \int \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}(aZ_n^X+bZ_n^Y)\ d\mu=a \int \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}aZ_n^X+b\int \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}Z_n^Y\ d\mu \\ =a\int Xd\mu+b\int Y\ d\mu$$

- Where do we need to interchange the limit and the integral?
- Does $\ f_n(X)\ +f_n(Y) = f_n(X+Y)$ hold when n goes to $\infty$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

\begin{align*}
\int\lim(aZ_{n}^{X}+bZ_{n}^{Y})&=\lim\int(aZ_{n}^{X}+bZ_{n}^{Y})~~~~\text{here}\\
&=\lim\left(\int aZ_{n}^{X}+\int bZ_{n}^{Y}\right)~~~~\text{linearity holds for simple functions}\\
&=\lim\int aZ_{n}^{X}+\lim\int bZ_{n}^{Y}\\
&=a\lim\int Z_{n}^{X}+b\lim\int Z_{n}^{Y}\\
&=a\int X+b\int Y.
\end{align*}

Comment: Thanks!!  Any thought on the second question?

Comment: No, that's not true.

Comment: Can you explain why?

Comment: The best explanation should go with counterexample, but it is a little trouble to make it. To see that, intuitively we can say that $1_{[a,b]}(X+Y)\ne 1_{[a,b]}(X)+1_{[a,b]}(Y)$ in general.